# Get tags from nested struct

Tags: go

Let say I have a struct look like:

```
type Employee struct {
    ID        uint32    `json:"id" sql:"id"`
    FirstName string    `json:"first_name" sql:"first_name"`
    LastName  string    `json:"last_name" sql:"last_name"`
    Department struct {
        Name string `json:"name" sql:"name"`
        Size int `json:"size" sql:"size"`
    }
}
```

The code below can not get tags from nested struct **Department**

```
func main(){
    t := reflect.TypeOf(&Employee{}).Elem()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)
        column := field.Tag.Get("sql")
        fmt.Println("column: ", column)
    }
}
```

Result:

```
column:  id
column:  first_name
column:  last_name
column:
```

Is there any way to get tags from nested struct ?? thanks.

Comment: The `Department` struct itself doesn't have tags, only its fields. You need to loop over the fields of `Department` itself.

Comment: Since it's nested you need to go one level deeper for each nesting level. `NumField` returns only the number of fields of the type on which you called it. And correspondingly `Field` only returns fields of the type on which you called it, it's not gonna return nested fields. https://play.golang.org/p/_NCk8n_bC51

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi and Happy New Year!

Your **Department** sub-structure doesn't have tags itself and you were trying to print them.

Your code should consider that the field being checked inside the loop can be struct itself and descend into it accordingly.

Here's a simple recursive version of the tags printer:

```
func printTags(t reflect.Type) {
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        field := t.Field(i)

        if field.Type.Kind() == reflect.Struct {
            printTags(field.Type)
            continue
        }

        column := field.Tag.Get("sql")
        fmt.Println("column: ", column)
    }
}

func main() {
    printTags(reflect.TypeOf(&Employee{}).Elem())
}
```

Then you have the output:

```
column:  id
column:  first_name
column:  last_name
column:  name
column:  size
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: btw, can I get value of each fields??

Comment: In the example above you are iterating over `Type`s information. If you want values, you should use `reflect.ValueOf` in `main` and use similar loop.